# Install php-solr package PECL extension on Dotdeb

Tags: solr, debian, php-7, pecl

We're using php 7 with debain 8 and Dotdeb. We want to use php-solr package. Are there any up to date instructions on how to package php extensions? All I can find is this old blog post from 2008.

https://www.dotdeb.org/2008/09/25/how-to-package-php-extensions-by-yourself/

Answer (score 0):

With PHP5.x

```
   sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   sudo apt-get install php5-dev
   sudo apt-get install php-pear
   sudo pecl install solr
   sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini"
   sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/solr.ini"
   sudo service apache2 restart
```

With PHP 7

```
   sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
   sudo apt-get install php-pear
   sudo pecl install solr
   sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini"
   sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/solr.ini"
   sudo service apache2 restart
```